# Prove by definition: $\lim_{x \to 1 } \frac{x^2+2}{(x-1)^2}=\infty $

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, definition

**Question:**
Prove by definition: $\;\lim\limits_{x \to 1 } \dfrac{x^2+2}{(x-1)^2}=\infty $

**My answer:**
First of all, pay attention to the following inequalities:

- $\left|\dfrac{x^2+2}{(x-1)^2}\right|= \dfrac{x^2+2}{(x-1)^2}>\dfrac{1}{(x-1)^2}\\$
  which is true for all $x$ because $x^2+2>1\;\;\forall x$
- $\dfrac{1}{(x-1)^2}>\dfrac{1}{\delta^2}\\$
  Indeed $\;\forall x \in (1-\delta;1+\delta) \Rightarrow |x-1|<\delta$
  and so $|x-1|^2<\delta^2 \implies
     \frac{1}{|x-1|^2}>\frac{1}{\delta^2}$ and this inequality is true for
  any $\delta>0$ we will choose
- But as $\,\delta = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{M}} \implies \delta^2 = \dfrac{1}{1/M}=M$.

Now we conclude by using all the inequalities that we’ve written above with the same justifications:

$\forall M>0 \; , \exists \delta = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{M}}>0\,$ such that $\,\forall x\!\in\!(1-\delta;1+\delta) \Rightarrow$ $\left| \dfrac{x^2+2}{(x-1)^2}\right|= \dfrac{x^2+2}{(x-1)^2}>  \dfrac{1}{(x-1)^2}>\dfrac{1}{\delta^2}=\dfrac{1}{(1/M)}=M$

and that finish the proof by the definition.

Is it correct? Thanks.

Comment: I think this proof is correct. What makes you doubt yourself?

Comment: @Asigan I just wanted to be sure that i ve understood well the prove by definition and that my writing is correct (as i don't know any IRL that can judge those things rigorously)

Comment: OK. This proof is very rigorous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I writte this answer to add precision and to mark this topic as solved.
The proof seems correct maybe for more precision i ve should written $\forall x \in (1-\delta;1+\delta) \setminus \left \{ 1 \right \}$ instead of $\forall x \in (1-\delta;1+\delta)$ only.